# Where is SRP-Z from?

Tags: authentication, reference-request, srp

The Stanford [license for SRP](http://srp.stanford.edu/license.txt) says:

> Broader use of the SRP authentication technology, such as variants
>   incorporating the use of an explicit server secret (SRP-Z), may
>   require a license;

Yet I cannot find a succinct description of the SRP-Z protocol and why it might be useful. As a follow up question assuming it is useful and patented when does the patent expire?

Comment: From the terms I understand that this is mutual authentication while SRP itself is client only authentication. If you mix in a server secret in the session key derivation then the above description may make sense. Did you search the patent database for SRP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25272/is-this-variant-of-srp-useful) both describes the SRP-Z variant and mentions that the patent should expire in three years.

I think the patent in question is this one, but I'm not sure: [US 6539479](https://www.google.fi/patents/US6539479). If it is, it seems to actually have expired earlier this year due to non-payment of fees. Looking it up on the [USPTO PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) says:

> Status:   Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362
>
> Status Date:  04-20-2015

It is still possible it [could be revived](http://www.clm.com/publication.cfm?ID=489) after such expiry, but IANAL, etc.